# Joining Tables to Retrieve Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables that link together. What I want to do is to generate a report card for all the students in a class.

table **students_info**

```
name      sex age students_ID
--------- --- --- -----------
Kinsley   M    12           1
Michael   m    12           2
Rhianna   f    22           3
```

Table **scores_panel**

```
1stCA 2ndCA exam students_ID subjectID
----- ----- ---- ----------- ---------
   23    15   42           1         1
   10    12    7           1         2
   43    15   62           1         3
   10    12   27           2         1
   10    12   57           2         2
   23    15   12           2         3
   11    12   27           3         1
   04    12   57           3         2
   13    25   12           3         3
```

Table **subject**

```
subjectname subjectID
----------- ---------
english             1
maths               2
biology             3
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
NAME KINSLEY
SEX M
AGE 12
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      23    15   42
maths        10    12    7
Biology      43    15   62
```

... and so on for all students

only one subject and scores retrieved instead of all

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$generate="SELECT students_info.name, subject.subjectname, scores_panel.1stCA, scores_panel.2ndCA, scores_panel.EXAM
FROM
students_info
LEFT JOIN
scores_panel
ON students_info.students_ID=scores_panel.students_ID
LEFT JOIN
subject
ON
subject.subjectID=scores_panel.subjectID ";

$fetch=mysql_query($generate);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch)or die(mysql_error()))
{
?>
**NAME:** 
<?PHP echo $row['name']; ?>
subject 1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
----------
<?PHP echo $row['subjectname']; ?>
<?PHP echo $row['1stCA']; ?>     
<?PHP echo $row['2ndCA']; ?>   
<?PHP echo $row['EXAM']; ?>

THIS IS YOUR REPORT CARD 
<?PHP } ?>
```

It  works, but displays only one subject for each student, instead of something like this:

```
  NAME KINSLEY
    SEX M
    AGE 12
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      23    15   42
maths        10    12    7
Biology      43    15   62


  NAME Rhianna 
    SEX F
    AGE 22
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      11    12   27
maths        04    12    57
Biology      13    25   12
```

... and so on for all students.

Comment: Also add what you have tried so far..

Comment: view my posted answer with fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Have you red this?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

If you already know about Table Joins, then you have to precise/show us what your problem is exactly (meaning what is the current status of your code)

Comment: thanks very much for your quick response but the stuff not give me what i want . i have edit my question with codes sample thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple [MySQL left join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) should solve this:

```
SELECT
st.name, st.sex, st.age,
sub.subjectname,
sc.1stCA, sc.2ndCA, sc.exam
FROM scores_panel AS sc
LEFT JOIN subject AS sub ON sub.subjectID = sc.subjectID
LEFT JOIN students_info AS st ON st.students_ID = sc.students_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/274f5/4)

And Query is

```
SELECT T1.NAME, T1.SEX, T1.AGE, T2.EXAM, T3.SUBNAME, T2.1CA, T2.2CA
   FROM TAB1 AS T1 LEFT JOIN TAB2 AS T2 ON T1.STUDENT_ID = T2.STUDENT_ID
      LEFT JOIN TAB3 AS T3 ON T2.SUBJ_ID = T3.SUBID;
```